# ng bootstrap dropdown menu styling using deep links

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I want to style the ng bootstrap dropdown menu, basically changing its width to auto. But I am not getting how should I target it using /deep/ links.

I want to target the ngbDropdownMenu.

Here is the HTML for it:

```
 <div ngbDropdown class="d-inline-block">
      <button class="btn btn-custom" id="columnToggle" ngbDropdownToggle ngbTooltip="Filter">
        <fa-icon [icon]="faColumns" title="Select to Show/Hide Columns"></fa-icon>
      </button>
      <div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="columnToggle">
        <button class="dropdown-item" *ngFor="let column of columnList">
          <label>
            <input type="checkbox" [checked]="column.selected" (change)="changeSelectedColumns.emit(column)" [disabled]="column.disabled"
            /> {{column.header}}
          </label>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add a class to your div nbgDropdownMenu

```
<div ngbDropdownMenu aria-labelledby="dropdownBasic1" class="custom">
     <button class="dropdown-item">Action - 1</button>
     <button class="dropdown-item">Another Action</button>
     <button class="dropdown-item">Something else is here</button>
</div>

.custom{
    background-color:Red;
    width:auto;
    padding:20px;
  }
```